# I am getting "You are not authorized to view this page" error while checking out to Cybersource payment gateway in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.6, payment-gateway, cybersource

I am using Magento 2.2.6 Enterprise edition.

In that when a user checkout to order an item, the system is throwing the error (403 Forbidden)

"You are not authorized to view this page. The transaction has not been processed"

This happens only for the logged in customers.

Can anyone please help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Have you checked logs?

Comment: Yes. Its is same for both logged-in and guest users. I can't get any clues from the log. Will it be something related to certificate or sever handshake issue?

Comment: You are using CyberSource?

Comment: Yes, I am using Cybersource as payment method/gateway.

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred because you may didn't add the required data to the request form data.

You have to configure your cyber source account according to your needs and then add those credentials.

Can you please follow the below URL once:

https://support.cybersource.com/s/article/I-receive-the-following-error-when-sending-a-Secure-Acceptance-request-You-are-not-authorized-to-view-this-page-The-transaction-has-not-been-processed